# Use variable form CSV Data Set in an Assertion Result filename in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have the following `Test Plan`

```
Thread Group
    - CSV Data Set Config
    - Controller
    - Assertion Results
```

There are multiple lines in my `csv` to get multiple threads in my group. The `csv`follows this pattern :

```
AB;12;under
CD;24;over
```

I want to save the `Assertion Results` in different directory depending on the last value of the `csv` (`under` or `over`).

To do so, I match the last value of the `csv` in a variable `V_POSITION` in my `CSV Data Set Config`. And I save my `Assertion Results` using this path name :

```
Results_Directory/${V_POSITION}/Results.csv
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I launch my test, the file is saved in the path name with literally `${V_POSITION}` as a directory. As if the variable `V_POSITION` doesn't have a value.

I used a Debug Sampler to verify the value of `V_POSITION` and, for every thread, it got `under` or `over`.

I suspect it's a variable scope problem, so I tried to use a global variable added directly to the `Test Plan`, but I always got the default value.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Provide your test plan. where do you give the path?  By any chance you set the path like this - "Results_Directory/${V_POSITION}/Results.csv"   instead of "Results_Directory/" + ${V_POSITION} "/Results.csv"?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. Do you want me to give you the complete jmx ? This example is a simplification of my real Test Plan, I use multiple variables to create my path, but it's the only one coming from a CSV (the others are Global variables declared in the Test Plan). So the path is written inside the text field "Filename" and literally the one I wrote.

Comment: I understand that. I just wanted to see the tree structure of the test plan to get an idea. How many thread groups you have? Do you create this V_POSITION  variable and save the results in the same thread group? If yes, then it can't be a scope issue!

Comment: My actually Test Plan get the really same structure than the one in my OP. One thread group and inside one CSV Data Set, one V_POSITON and one Assertion results using the V_POSTION in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (I'm talking about JMeter 2.12) it is not possible to use JMeter Variables as a part of file names in Assertion Results, CSV Data Set Config, other listeners, etc.

However it is possible to use properties so you can implement what you want

1. Convert your `V_POSITION` JMeter Variable to JMeter Property (you can leave the name as is. See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide for details on how this could be done
2. Change path in Assertion Results listener to look like

   ```
   Results_Directory/${__property(V_POSITION,,)}/Results.csv
   ```
3. Make sure that folders `under`, `over` etc. exist, JMeter won't create folders for you and results will be going nowhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I got a little improvement, but not fully what i'm looking for. I set my variable as a property and call this property for my path, but it only writes the results in the last value of V_POSITION read... For example, if I have "under" in the last line of my CSV, all the assertion results are saved in the folder "under".